# Reordering an array based on sorted indices in another array

Tags: c++

I'm doing a binary radix sort algorithm assignment and have trouble with the last step. From the instructions I have been given, I know what I have to do, but don't know how to implement it in C++. To better understand what I'm asking, I'll give an example. Let's say we have an array of integers:

```
int array[5] = {5, 24, 8, 9, 10}
```

With the value 5 at index 0, 24 at index 2 etc.
Now let's say I put those indices in an array and reorder them (in my case, sort them)

```
int indices[5] = {3, 4, 0, 1, 2}
```

What I need to do is, based on these reordered indices, reorder the initial array. So for example, since the index 3 is now at index 0 in its array, I have to move 9, which in my example is at index 3, to index 1 in its array as well. The final array would look something like this:

```
array[5] = {9, 10, 5, 24, 8}
```

I'm not sure what this is called, so I have trouble finding it online. Does someone know the answer to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to do all the swaps necessary to sort the index array identically on the `array` array? What keeps you from doing that?

Comment: The indices are sorted by another sorting algorithm, so I only need to swap the values from the array array that were swaped in the inex array

Comment: So you are saying that the sorting is done outside of your control? In that case you will probably end up doing more or less what 3Dave proposes. Possible as a temporary array which then gets copy to the original in order to have a quasi-inplace effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have to do this in-place:

```
const int len = 5;
int newArray[len];

for(int i=0; i < len; ++i)
{
  newArray[i] = array[indices[i]];
}

memcpy(array,newArray,len * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Quite an assumption. Otherwise great.

Comment: @Yunnosch It's Sunday morning. My brain is in full-on cache miss mode. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually an algorithm to do this in-place, assuming you can also modify the indices array. The algorithm can be summarized as follows:

- Consider index `i`, you want to put `array[indices[i]]` into `array[i]`. To avoid overwriting `array[i]`, let's first store it in another variable `value`.
- Now that we've used `array[indices[i]]`, we can safely overwrite it with the value we want in index `indices[i]`, which is `array[indices[indices[i]]]`.
- Repeat this process, and eventually we'll get to an index `j` such that `indices[j] == i`. We can just do `array[j] = value`. The reason such `j` exists is that: a permutation can always be decomposed into a set of "cycles". See [the Wikipedia article on permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) for more information.
- Repeat the above steps for every other index that has not been processed yet. We can use the `indices` array to keep track of which indices have been processed.

The whole algorithm has a time complexity of O(n), where `n` is the length of the array. It only requires O(1) additional storage (the `value` variable).

Here's the C++ implementation of the algorithm:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int N = 5;
    int array[N] = {5, 24, 8, 9, 10};
    int indices[N] = {3, 4, 0, 1, 2};
    // After processing index `i`, mark the index by setting `indices[i] = -1`.

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (indices[i] == -1) continue;  // index `i` has been processed, skip
        int value = array[i];
        int x = i, y = indices[i];  // `x` is the current index, `y` is the "target" index
        while (y != i) {
            indices[x] = -1;  // mark index as processed
            array[x] = array[y];
            x = y;
            y = indices[x];
        }
        // Now `x` is the index that satisfies `indices[x] == i`.
        array[x] = value;
        indices[x] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```